R packages glmer and brms: correctly defining fixed and random/grouping effects for binomial family
(Sidenote: I'd prefer the frequentist approach (glmer), if possible, since it is more common in my field. Feel free to comment on either or both packages. Any feedback GREATLY appreciated!)
Summary:

93 subjects
40 choice sets per subject (3720 observations in total)
two-alternative forced choice
3 attributes: at1, at2, at3 with (4,4,5) levels, coded as factors
5 socio-demographic covariates: sd1 to sd5, coded as either factors (if levels, e.g., 1-5, or continuous and scaled, e.g., age(sd1) ranging from 18-40). Should control for sd1 to sd4. To be tested: interaction between at3 and sd5
Data format: long, i.e. (exemplary)




id
choiceid
alternative
at1
at2
at3
sd1
...
sd5




1
1
1
5
4
4
-0.2
...
4


1
1
2
7
6
2
-0.2
...
4



Q1: Is my variable coding and data structure resonable so far?
Because alternatives are unlabeled, I'd say that with all attributes being 0 for both alternatives, probability of choice being 0 or 1 should be 50% for everyone. Since it is binomial logit, I'd expect an estimated fixed intercept of 0 (odds ratio=1).
Thus Q2: Would you include a fixed and/or a random intercept for subjects in an unlabeled binomial model?
Since there are multiple observations per subject, I suppose I should use some random/grouping effect for them. Also, since choice depends on choice set, following Andrew Heiss for brms, I should nest choiceid within id. (0 + at1 + at2 + at3 | choiceid | id). I am having trouble, though, understanding why anyone should have different slopes depending on the choice set. (It is reasonable for subjects to have different slopes for the attributes in general, though.)
Q3: Should (... | choiceid | id) be used? If so, how can I implement that in glmer?
Again following Andrew, I interact all attributes with all socio-demographic covariates, except sd5, which is only supposed to interact with at3 for theoretical reasons:
choice ~ (at1 + at2 + at3) * (sd1 + sd2 + sd3 + sd4) + sd5 + at3:sd5 + (0 + at1 + at2 + at3 | choiceid | id)

This model is very complex and difficult to estimate/converge. Q4: How can I reduce the model?
For background:
Main simplified null hypotheses (controlled for sd1, sd2, sd3, sd4):

H_0_1: choice unrelated to at1.
H_0_2: choice unrelated to at2.
H_0_3: choice unrelated to at3.
H_0_3_1: relationship between at3 and choice not interacted by sd5.

To my surprise, the simplest model
m0 <- glmer(choice ~ 1 + (1 | id), data = data, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

is singular fit, has basically no fixed or random intercept or variance:
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: choice ~ 1 + (1 | id)
   Data: data
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+05))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 10318.0  10331.9  -5157.0  10314.0     7438 

Scaled residuals: 
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
    -1     -1      0      1      1 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 7440, groups:  id, 93

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -2.054e-07  2.319e-02       0        1
optimizer (bobyqa) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

With brms:
 Family: bernoulli 
  Links: mu = logit 
Formula: choice ~ 1 + (1 | choiceid | id) 
   Data: dfs_social (Number of observations: 7440) 
  Draws: 4 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
         total post-warmup draws = 4000

Multilevel Hyperparameters:
~id (Number of levels: 93) 
              Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sd(Intercept)     0.02      0.01     0.00     0.05 1.00     3963     2220

Regression Coefficients:
          Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
Intercept     0.00      0.02    -0.05     0.05 1.00     8679     2987

But by looking at the choice data, I can see that after aggregating choice for each subject, the percentage of choice=0 ranges from 15-100% among subjects, with mean 45% with standard deviation 24.2. To my understanding, this means there is quite some variation among subjects and with all other predictors absent, individuals should have different intercepts. Why do I not see any variance between subjects?
In full, I think the model should be like this:
model_brm <- brm(
  bf(choice ~ (at1 + at2 + at3 ) * (sd1 + sd2 + sd3 + sd4) + sd5 + at3:sd5 + (0 + at1 + at2 + at3 | choiceid | id)),
  data = data,
  family = bernoulli(link = "logit"),
  chains = 4, cores = 4, warmup = 1000, iter = 4000, seed = 1234,
  threads = threading(2), # refresh = 0,
  control = list(adapt_delta = 0.95)


I think you may be getting weird results because of the forced choice setting; you really need a conditional logistic regression framework. From Muff et al doi 10.1111/1365-2656.13087: "By interpreting the intercepts as a random effect with a large (fixed) variance, inference for random-slope models becomes feasible with standard Bayesian techniques, or with frequentist methods that allow one to fix the variance of a random effect.". You can achieve this with the map argument in glmmTMB, or see ?lme4::modular ...
